# catching discarded events in boost statechart library

Tags: c++, boost, state-machine, statechart

I am looking at Boost StateChart lib documentation, and I am not able to find out a way to catch abnormal events.

For example, if I am in state A, which handles only EventA, and I call

```
machine.proces_event(EventB())
```

The event seems to get silently ignored. Is there a way for me to catch those, so I can log the state & the illegal action?

Thank you.

Comment: I have since found the answer to this. We just need to implement consumed_event function in our stateMachine.

    void unconsumed_event( const sc::event_base & e) {}

Comment: please add an answer to your question

Comment: I will. But when I tried to add that answer yesterday, I couldn't because I have less than n points, and was trying to answer in less than 8 hours of posting the question.

Answer (score 6):

I have since found the answer to this. We just need to implement consumed_event function in our stateMachine.

```
void unconsumed_event( const sc::event_base & e) {}
```